# Syntax error with input statement response

Tags: python, datetime, syntax-error, reminders

Whenever i try to give input for the three input statements in my code, i get an error.

I have tried running the input statements without any of the other code, and they worked fine. It is only when i include them in this code that they break.

```
# This code is a reminder/alert system.
# This code imports the datetime functions required to allow the program to detect if there is an event.
import datetime
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
# Textual month, day and year   
d2 = today.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
# Time module import.
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# This code gets user input for an event and the day it happens.
eventName = input("What is the event name? ")
eventDate = input("What date is the event? Use the textual month/day/year (September 2, 2019). ")
eventTime = input("What time is the event? Use numeric millitary time H/M/S (14:52:30) ")

# This code defines the getRemind function that will tell the user if they do or do not have an alert for the day and/or time.
def getRemind(event, date, time):
    if d2 in eventDate: 
        return("Reminder: " + eventName + " today!")
    NACharlotte = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=-4)
    if NACharlotte in evenTime:
        return("Reminder: " + eventName + " at " + eventTime + "!")
    if d2 in eventDate and NACharlotte in eventTime:
        return("Reminder: " + eventName + " today at " + eventTime + "!")
    print("You do not have any events today.")

# This code will print the results of the getRemind function.
print(getRemind(eventName, eventDate, eventTime))
```

The expected result is that the user should be able to enter data for all three input statements. The actual result is one of two things: If a two word statement such as Bus home or Project presentations is entered, a 'SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing' is returned. If a one-word input is used, then a NameError is returned saying that the input is not defined.

Comment: There is a typo in `if NACharlotte in evenTime:`. It should be `eventTime` instead of `evenTime`. Also, that statement itself makes little sense to me - You seem to be using `in` to compare `datetime`s.

Comment: Sounds like you're running this with Python 2.x, in which case you need to use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code on line 24: `evenTime` does not exist. You mean `eventTime`.

Code works fine for me after making that change.

Comment: I get a `TypeError` at `if NACharlotte in eventTime:` with the message `TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not datetime.datetime`.